# Transfer admin privileges to another account

Tags: macos, permissions, filesystems

I have one admin account that's empty, and my account which is admin but barely has any privileges at all (can't save anything in Finder, etc.).

Could I somehow transfer my empty account's privileges to my new account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to log in to the other account and go to System Preferences, then Users & Groups. From there you should be able to adjust your account's privileges.

[These are the screens you will see.](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-users-in-mac-os-x-lion.html)